# Mongo: add fields with count of how many times another field appears

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm new to MongoDB. I am writing an app using mongoose and NodeJS. I start with this collection:

```
[
  { name: "Joe", hobby: "Food"},
  { name: "Lyn", hobby: "Food"},
  { name: "Rex", hobby: "Play"},
  { name: "Rex", hobby: "Shop"},
  ...
]
```

And I want to output a subset of the documents with two new fields: `nameCount` showing how many times the document's name value appears, and `hobbyCount` showing the same thing for the document's hobby:

```
[
  { name: "Joe", hobby: "Food", nameCount: 1, hobbyCount: 2 },
  { name: "Lyn", hobby: "Food", nameCount: 1, hobbyCount: 2 },
  { name: "Rex", hobby: "Play", nameCount: 2, hobbyCount: 1 },
  { name: "Rex", hobby: "Shop", nameCount: 2, hobbyCount: 1 }
]
```

From my research and fiddling about I got the following query to work but it seems over the top, inefficient and over-complicated.

```
db.members.aggregate([
  {$skip: 0},
  {$limit: 4},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "members",
      let: { name: "$name"},
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$name", "$$name"] } } },
        { $count: "count" }
      ],
      as: "nameCount"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$nameCount" },
  { $addFields: { nameCount: "$nameCount.count" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "members",
      let: { hobby: "$hobby"},
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$hobby", "$$hobby"] } } },
        { $count: "count" }
      ],
      as: "hobbyCount"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$hobbyCount" },
  { $addFields: { hobbyCount: "$hobbyCount.count" } }
]);
```

[**Mongo Playground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q5wWHmdPZG3)

It's bugging me in particular, not just that the query seems overdone, but that it looks like I'm running two new searches per record found through the whole collection when maybe the `nameCount` and `hobbyCount` could be compiled in a single search.

#### Update

Valijon posted an answer that made me realize that I oversimplified my actual problem when trying to post the minimum required.  In reality the collection is filtered (with a $match, $skip and $take) before the first lookup that I posted. As a result, Valijon's answer doesn't actually work for me, although it's a great answer for the way I originally posed the problem.  Sorry, I'm updating the OP

[See the playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hZzuzTnUJJs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** We need to use only 1 `$lookup` (we match both by name and hobby) and count `nameCount` and `hobbyCount` by applying `$filter` or `$reduce` operators

```
db.members.aggregate([
  {
    $skip: 1
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "members",
      let: {
        name: "$name",
        hobby: "$hobby"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$name",
                    "$$name"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$hobby",
                    "$$hobby"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "count"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      hobby: 1,
      nameCount: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$count",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $add: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$name",
                      "$$this.name"
                    ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      hobbyCount: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$count",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$hobby",
                "$$this.hobby"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mnSir_ZsIFq)

Comment: You know your stuff! Please see my revised question; I oversimplified my problem so much that although your answer is great it doesn't apply to what I'm trying to do (my fault for posting a bad question). The actual query has facets as well, with a `$match` at the beginning, and a `$skip` and `$limit` in the pipeline where I compile the data.  Trying to replace my old `$lookup` with your solution doesn't work.  See https://mongoplayground.net/p/_nDxBQl5-4M

Comment: @BeetleJuice Check my answer please, maybe this time we've found the best solution to avoid performing `$lookup` twicely...

Comment: Actually I adapted your initial solution.  I just added the filtering (match, skip, limit) at the end of the pipeline instead of at the beginning.  See https://mongoplayground.net/p/b8I1DuohjsC and tell me how you think it compares to your updated answer efficiency wise